# Vagrant (ionic-box) not syncing on host folder

Tags: android, cordova, vagrant, ionic-framework, vagrantfile

Why is it when I install ionic-box (for Ionicframework) it's not syncing in my folder?
I added this line

`config.vm.synced_folder "projects", "/vagrant_projects"`

to Vagrantfile but it's not working. i still need to create manually the folder `vagrant_projects` in `home/vagrant` directory which I thought will be create automatically when creating/installing ionic-box.

I already added a new project inside `vagrant_projects` but i noticed it is not reflecting in the host folder `projects`.

BtW, I created the folder `projects` inside the directory where i extract the `Vagrantfile`.

Here's my reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/ionic-box-vagrant-configuration-hybrid-mobile-apps/ and http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-building-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config.vm.synced_folder "projects", "/vagrant_projects" will create vagrant_projects folder at / not home/vagrant. So the path of your folder **vagrant_projects** will be /vagrant_projects not home/vagrant/vagrant_projects.

Your configuration is correct just login to your vm via **vagrant ssh** and execute following command

> ls /vagrant_projects

you should be able to see your synced data now.

[vagrant tutorial](http://www.brownfort.com/vagrant-tutorial/)

Comment: is there a way I can add it at `home/vagrant/vagrant_projects` ? or  its okay if it's in `/vagrant_projects` ?

Comment: config.vm.synced_folder "projects", "/home/vagrant/vagrant_projects"

Comment: thanks! I will configure it now. I will accept your answer if it works!

Comment: @PrashantKumar - Great Work! Worked like a charm. Thanks